# In TensorFlow's C++ api, how to generate a graph file to visualization with tensorboard?

Tags: api, tensorflow, tensorboard

There is a way to create a file with Python, which can be visualization by TensorBoard(see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard#usage)). I have tried with this code and it works well.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.add(1, 2,)
b = tf.multiply(a, 3)
c = tf.add(4, 5,)
d = tf.multiply(c, 6,)
e = tf.multiply(4, 5,)
f = tf.div(c, 6,)
g = tf.add(b, d)
h = tf.multiply(g, f)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(h))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("output", sess.graph)
    print(sess.run(h))
    writer.close()
```

Now I am using TensorFlow API to create my computations. **How can I visualize my computations with TensorBoard?**

There have a [FileWrite](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/write-file) interface in C++ api also, but I have not seen any example. Is it the same interface ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you want `tensorflow::EventsWriter` from `tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.h`. You'll need to manually create an Event object to use it though.

The python code in tf.summary.FileWriter handles a lot of the details for you though, I'd suggest only using the C++ API if absolutely necessary... Is there a compelling reason to implement your training in C++?

Answer (score 0):

See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48610803/how-i-can-use-filewrite-summary-in-tensorflow-c-api-to-view-it-in-tensorboard/48702823#48702823), which gives you a 26-liner in c++ to do this:

```
#include <tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


void write_scalar(tensorflow::EventsWriter* writer, double wall_time, tensorflow::int64 step,
                  const std::string& tag, float simple_value) {
  tensorflow::Event event;
  event.set_wall_time(wall_time);
  event.set_step(step);
  tensorflow::Summary::Value* summ_val = event.mutable_summary()->add_value();
  summ_val->set_tag(tag);
  summ_val->set_simple_value(simple_value);
  writer->WriteEvent(event);
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  std::string envent_file = "./events";
  tensorflow::EventsWriter writer(envent_file);
  for (int i = 0; i < 150; ++i)
    write_scalar(&writer, i * 20, i, "loss", 150.f / i);

  return 0;
}
```