# How I can use fileWrite summary in tensorFlow C++ API to view it in Tensorboard

Tags: c++, tensorflow

Is there anyway I can get the tensor name corresponding to FileWriter so that I can write my summary out to view them in Tensorboard? My application is C++ based, so I have to use C++ to do training.

Comment: Thanks for Patwie's help. The code is really useful. A question on top of the asked question. I can view the summary (scalar, histograms) How to view the computation graph in tensorboard from files dumped out using C++ API? I could not find the graph on tensorboard while I can view the summaries.

Answer (score 5):

The FileWriter is not a tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("test", sess.graph)
    print([n for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node])
```

will give you an empty graph. You are interested in the EventsWriter. (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/994226a4a992c4a0205bca9e2f394cb644775ad7/tensorflow/core/util/events_writer_test.cc#L38-L52).

A minimal working example is

```
#include <tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


void write_scalar(tensorflow::EventsWriter* writer, double wall_time, tensorflow::int64 step,
                  const std::string& tag, float simple_value) {
  tensorflow::Event event;
  event.set_wall_time(wall_time);
  event.set_step(step);
  tensorflow::Summary::Value* summ_val = event.mutable_summary()->add_value();
  summ_val->set_tag(tag);
  summ_val->set_simple_value(simple_value);
  writer->WriteEvent(event);
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  std::string envent_file = "./events";
  tensorflow::EventsWriter writer(envent_file);
  for (int i = 0; i < 150; ++i)
    write_scalar(&writer, i * 20, i, "loss", 150.f / i);

  return 0;
}
```

This gives you a nice loss curve using `tensorboard --logdir .`

[image]

**edit**
Adding a histogram can be done in the same way:

```cpp
#include <tensorflow/core/lib/histogram/histogram.h>
#include <tensorflow/core/util/events_writer.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <float.h>


void write_histogram(tensorflow::EventsWriter* writer, double wall_time, tensorflow::int64 step,
                     const std::string& tag, tensorflow::HistogramProto *hist) {
  tensorflow::Event event;
  event.set_wall_time(wall_time);
  event.set_step(step);
  tensorflow::Summary::Value* summ_val = event.mutable_summary()->add_value();
  summ_val->set_tag(tag);
  summ_val->set_allocated_histo(hist);
  writer->WriteEvent(event);


}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  std::string envent_file = "./events";
  tensorflow::EventsWriter writer(envent_file);


  // write histogram
  for (int time_step = 0; time_step < 150; ++time_step) {

    // a very simple histogram
    tensorflow::histogram::Histogram h;
    for (int i = 0; i < time_step; i++)
      h.Add(i);

    // convert to proto
    tensorflow::HistogramProto *hist_proto = new tensorflow::HistogramProto();
    h.EncodeToProto(hist_proto, true);

    // write proto
    write_histogram(&writer, time_step * 20, time_step, "some_hist", hist_proto);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you also add an example on how to write out a summary histogram?

Comment: Despite this being another question, see my edits for writing histograms. Please mark the question as answered if the proposed solutions was helpful.

Comment: I used the C++ code provided to output some event files. I can see event files are created. When I tried to see the results on tensorboard gui from my firefox. I got message saying "loading active dashboards". Yet, after about 1 minutes of loading, I got "inactive" stauts of dashboard and nothing showed up in my tensorboard gui. I could not see the curve that you saw. 

what may be the problem? I know this might be a different question and I asked the same in a separate thread.

Comment: Yes this *is* a different questions. Are you sure tensorboard is pointing to the correct directory?

Comment: yes. it pointed to the correct directory. I can see events.tfevents* files are generated in this directory.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found it is because of the version of firefox that I used. If I switched to an old firefox version, I can see the tensorboard correctly.     I got a relevant question. How to dump and view the graph from C++ code?

Comment: did you manage to get this working?