# debugging c++ tensorflow programs

Tags: c++, debugging, tensorflow

I am looking for tips on how to debug tensor flow graph execution written in c++. In particular calls to session::Run produce the error "specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph" and I am looking for ways to debug my graph.

// data is a std::vector

```
std::vector names = {"feature1","feature2","feature3","feature4"};

std::vector<std::pair<tf::string, tf::Tensor>> input_tensor;
std::vector<tf::Tensor> output_tensors;

//  create the Run input tensor
for (uint i=0; i < gamma_transformed_data.size();i++)
{
  tf::Tensor tensorValue(tf::DT_FLOAT, tf::TensorShape({1,1}));
  tensorValue.flat<float>().data()[0] = data[i];
  std::pair <tf::string, tf::Tensor> pair = std::make_pair (names[i],tensorValue);
  input_tensor.push_back(pair);
}


//execute the graph
check_status(ReadBinaryProto(tf::Env::Default(),protobuf_model_filepath, &graph));
check_status(tf::NewSession(tf::SessionOptions(), &session));
check_status(session->Create(graph));
check_status(session->Run(input_tensor, {"results"}, {}, &output_tensors));

session->Run returns false and status.ToString() = //"Invalid argument: Tensor xyz:0, specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph"
```

Comment: With Tensorflow, you need to give the data to your program by either using `feed_dict` or the Dataset API. I would suggest editing your question with the relevant code so we can help you debug it.

Comment: I am using the C++ API which does things differently than Python. What I am really looking for are common strategies that people use to debug C++ Tensorflow programs.

Comment: Oh, I see. If you can, I would suggest looking into Tensorboard, as this seems to be the industry accepted solution to this problem. Link: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard

Comment: For doing this with c++ Tensorflow, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951674/in-tensorflows-c-api-how-to-generate-a-graph-file-to-visualization-with-tens